# How to show limit definition of $e^{z}$ holds if $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

It is well known that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
e^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+  \frac{x}{n}\right)^n.
$$
This follows quickly by considering logarithms and using L'Hospital's rule.
However, for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ this would involve taking complex logarithms.
I am not convinced that this proof still works and I was wondering if there is another simple proof of this fact when $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

EDIT: For definition I am using the Taylor series $$e^z := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}.$$
I am okay with all the standard alternative definitions and properties of $e^x$ when $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so feel free to use those if the real case can somehow be extended to the complex case.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiC2VPna7qk Answers my question.

Comment: Just an idea: Prove that the limit converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and its derivative too. Then it is a holomorphic function and since it coincides with $e^x$ on $\mathbb{R}$, they must be equal on whole $\mathbb{C}$ according to the identity theorem.

Answer (score 2):

See the Wikipedia entry on characterizations of the function $e^x$ for $x \in \mathbb R$, and suggestions for [extending each of these characterizations to a larger domain.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Larger_domains)

Comment: Nice link, been a long time +1

Comment: nullUser: I'm sorry I wasn't of greater help...I'll do some more searching through my text for my notes about extending the domain to the complex numbers.